# Strange behaviour with Collections - sort method

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

I have strange problem with sorting my list.

At first, I have a custom class with

```
private List<Player> players;
```

So, in players are some items, for example 2 - "Player 1" and "Player 2".

It is Player class basically:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int points = 0; 
}
```

I have a function used for sorting players (comparing points):

```
public String getActualRanking() {

    for(int z = 0; z < players.size(); z++) {
        Log.d("COLSORT", players.get(z).getName());
    }

    String message = "";

    List<Player> temp = players;
    Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Player>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Player player, Player t1) {
            return Integer.valueOf(t1.getPoints()).compareTo(player.getPoints());
        }
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        message += Integer.toString(temp.get(i).getPoints()) + " pkt - " + temp.get(i).getName() + "\n";
    }


    for(int z = 0; z < players.size(); z++) {
        Log.d("COLSORT", players.get(z).getName());
    }

    return message;
}
```

Why there is 2 Log.d? Because first log is:

```
D/COLSORT﹕ Player 1
D/COLSORT﹕ Player 2
```

But second is:

```
D/COLSORT﹕ Player 2
D/COLSORT﹕ Player 1
```

The question is: why? Why Collections.sort do sorting on "players" list if I created "temp" list to be sorted and "players" are not used in this function anymore? I really don't understand that behaviour :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Player> temp = players;
```

This does not create a copy of the `players` list.  `temp` and `players` are now referring to the *same* list.  There is no difference between `temp` and `players` anymore.

If you want to make a copy so that `temp` can be sorted without changing `players`, write

```
List<Player> temp = new ArrayList<>(players);
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much :)